# Using a function in nested objects in Drools

Tags: object, nested, drools

I am working with a project with nested objects.
I have 3 questions.

1). I have a rule in which I need to make use of a function. If I use this function on a variable in a nested object it does not work (I get a compilation error). If I assign the nested object to a local variable and then apply the function, it works. Why? Is it because of Mavel and the way it handles nested objects?

Using the nested object accessor approach (compilation error "Unable to Analyse Expression"):

```
ObjectA( objectB. ( (someFunction(someVariable)) == 0 ) )
```

Using a non nested object accessor approach (this works):

```
ObjectA( $objectB : objectB )
ObjectB( (someFunction(someVariable)) == 0 ) from $objectB
```

2). Is there any other reason why I should not use the nested object approach? 
Or, said in other words, is there a difference between this:

```
ObjectA( $objectB : objectB )
ObjectB( someVariable == 0 ) from $objectB`
```

And this:

```
ObjectA( objectB. ( someVariable == 0 ) )`
```

3). Is it possible to assign a nested object with access on its variables to a local variable, e.g. because of use in some other rule (extends) which conditions for some particular reason I do not want to include in this rule?

```
ObjectA( $objectB : objectB. ( someVariable == 0 ) )`
```

I am using Drools 6.5.0 although most coding is done in KIE workbench 6.5.0. I use a local Java mirror project to get better indications on compilation errors and so.

Comment: `ObjectA( objectB. ( ... ))` is syntactically in error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am afraid I don't understand it. What do you mean with "syntactically in error". The coding with nested objects is working perfectly if I do not use functions, following the guidelines in chapter 8.8.3.3.7 [link](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/) of the Drools 6.5.0 documentation.

Comment: BTW I have already seen that question number 3 is impossible because of a compilation casting error from mvel to Java.

Comment: Sorry! Although I'm not sure how much of a general expression is permitted within a nested accessor. Provide a complete example and raise a jira at the Drools error reporting site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will do so and post a comment with a link to the report.

Comment: Issue is reported: [link](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1741) . But as far as I have read nested objects are delegated to mvel so I think that if you need to use a function you can not use the nested object accessor approach which, to me, implies that there is basically no difference either in using one approach or other beside code cleaning. Thanks a lot, laune!

Comment: I detected that the same compilation error occurs as well when just using a more complex operation on variables in nested objects as well, probably has to do with the brackets. This also produces the same compilation error: `ObjectA( objectB. ( (someVariable == 0 || someVariable == 1 ) || (someVariable > -1 || someVariable < 2 )) )`

Comment: Trying eval with plain Java used to be a good alternative when MVEL couldn't cope with an expression. Not sure whether 6.x still lets you.

Comment: I can do something like this `ObjectA( someFunction(getObjectB().getSomeVariable()) == 0  )` but then I am not using the nested accessor approach anymore.